# What exactly is meant by "observing" a quantum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, observers, observables, quantum-measurements

When a quantum is observed, it falls into a specific state. Is just looking somewhere also considered "observing" or does this have to be with electronic devices, or does something have to be absorbed?

Comment: Not an expert here, but I think a measurement is necessary.

Comment: What's a "quantum"?

Comment: @Lambda that's [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Answer (score 0):

Observing usually has two possible meanings: interacting with a system  or measuring a system. Interacting with a system means that instead of just having the Hamiltonian of the bare system, say $H_0$, you also have the Hamiltonian of the interaction, $H_I$, and the Hamiltonian of the system it interacts with, $H'$. Instead of solving Schrödinger's equation for the full Hamiltonian
$$H=H_0+H_I+H'\:,$$
we approximate and say that the state collapsed to the "measured" state, which is one of the possible states the system $H'$ "allows". Now, does always measuring some property of the system involve interacting with it? Not always, check [interaction-free measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction-free_measurement).